How to check if a user is new to the application on User class

I want to check if a user is being registered first time in the firebase. I know there is UserCredential object that comes with additionalDataAttributes to check .isNewUser but how do I do it within snapshot.
I tried printing the code, but nothing.

On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

If you can't access the UserCredential object, you can compare the creationTime and lastSignInTime properties in the user.metadata. If they are the same or really close to each other, the user is new.

How do I set User class from snapshot?

Your snapshot.data! is a User as far as I can tell. https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/authStateChanges.html --- Also see What should I do when someone answers my question?
